# How to define a range of values while writing IF condition in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am trying to write a NestedIF to sort out if people are Young, Middle aged or Old. now I want to get "Middle Aged" for all the values between 25 to 65.

Comment: Put your code in question.

Comment: FYI - For future posts, if you tag VBA without providing any attempted code a lot of users will down-vote you.

Comment: You should put what code you have into the question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry guys. new to Stakeoverflow.. will follow the rules from next time.

Comment: These are not guidelines specific to Stack Overflow. Experienced developers want you to make an initial attempt anywhere you ask a question on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
=IF(A1<25,"Young",IF(AND(A1>=25,A1<=65),"Middle Aged","Old"))
```